# Pusher PHP API: what are the minimum files to keep in Production?

Tags: php, composer-php, pusher

Using Pusher in Dev with the PHP APi (pusher-php-server) works fine, but I installed it with composer and it brought a large amount of files including tests and many more stuff that seem irrelevant for my Prod deployment.

Is there an easy way to find out what files can be removed and how to use the PHP API without the fancy autoload etc, to slim out the number of files to be kept for Prod?
I currently have in mu Pusher API root:

- composer
- paragonie
- psr
- pusher
- autoload.php

For a total of little less than 3MB.

I figured the core of it is placed here: ./pusher/pusher/pusher-php-server/src but I have no idea how to use it properly since currently my php code does:

```
require '../ext/pusher/autoload.php';
$pusher = new Pusher\Pusher([...]);
$pusher->trigger([...]);
```

(this code is called every time a message needs to be sent to the channel)

Comment: _"how to use the PHP API without the fancy autoload"_ - If you're using comopser, then you should use composers autoloader, not the libraries own (if that is what you're using now). Not using that autoloader is a bad idea since you will need to manually include every single file the libraries need. To make sure only the core files are loaded (without tests etc), install the packages with: `composer install --no-dev` and it should omit tests etc (if the library is properly configured). Don't remove things by hand or you will need to do that everytime you run composer update.

Comment: Thanks, `install --no-dev` did remove a test folder and half the size. I can still see some test folders but I'll not waste much more time with this... If you answer this I'll accept it.